# Kerberos ticket in tmux session

Tags: permissions, tmux, session, kerberos

I have two servers, on both I need to authenticate with kerberos. If I don't have a valid kerberos ticket, I cannot login on server A. On Server B, I can login without a kerberos ticket, it will prompt for my password and create a kerberos ticket during login.

On server A I can start a `tmux` session and it can run forever, without me ever running into any problems.

When running a `tmux` session on server B, as soon as I log out from the server, I lose permission to access my files. I tried using `k5reauth`, but it does not seem to work.

How can I run a `tmux` session on server B, without losing my kerberos ticket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging out destroys your ticket . you need to somehow:

1. Find it
2. Copy it
3. point your kerberos libs to it
4. keep renewing it (optional).

For 1 klist will help : first line says ticket cache: 
2 depends on 1, if it is FILE:/tmp/krb5_XXXXXXX of DIR:/SOME/PATH
all you have to do is copy it:

```
cp /tmp/krb5_XXXXXXX /tmp/krb5_tmux_XXXXXXX)
```

Make sure that only you can read it.

For 3 set env var  KRB5CCNAME to FILE:/tmp/krb5_tmux_XXXXXXX:

```
export KRB5CCNAME=FILE:/tmp/krb5_tmux_XXXXXXX
```

step 4 can be achieved with krenew  from the kstart package (look it up)